# Using Google Http Batch with Google Classroom Api

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-classroom

I am writing an app (using PHP) which will add students to a Google Classroom.  I am following the documentation at:

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch

I am using the batch request to add multiple students to a Google Classroom.  However the batch request appears to fail.  My code is as follows:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);

$service->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);

$batch = $service->createBatch();

$courseId = "123456";
$studentEmails = ["user1@domain.com","user2@domain.com"];

foreach($studentEmails as $email) {
  $student = new Google_Service_Classroom_Student(['userId' => $email]);
  $request = $service->courses_students->create($courseId, $student);
  $requestId = $email;
  $batch->add($request, $requestId);
}

$results = $batch->execute();


foreach($results as $responseId => $student) {
  $studentEmail = substr($responseId, strlen('response-') );
  if ($student instanceof Google_Service_Exception) {
    $e = $student;
    printf("Error adding user '%s' to the course: %s\n", $studentEmail,
      $e->getMessage());
  } else {
    printf("User '%s' was added as a student to the course.\n",
        $student->profile->name->fullName, $courseId);
  }
}

$service->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);
```

The output of this code is:

```
Error adding user 'user1@domain.com' to the course: Not Found ...
```

However, both the user and course exist on the domain.  If I remove the batch code and make the request one at a time the students are successfully added to the classroom, which leads me to believe I am missing something with the batch request

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first check [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php) and make sure that you complete the steps described in the rest of the given page to be able to make requests to the Classroom API as also mentioned in [using client libraries](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch#using-client-libraries) in Batching Requests.

After successfully installing the libraries and set them up, you may then try the code samples which demonstrates how to make batch requests using the Google APIs client libraries.

```
$courseId = '123456';
$studentEmails = array('alice@example.edu', 'bob@example.edu');
$service->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = $service->createBatch();
foreach($studentEmails as $studentEmail) {
  $student = new Google_Service_Classroom_Student(array(
    'userId' => $studentEmail
  ));
  $request = $service->courses_students->create($courseId, $student);
  $requestId = $studentEmail;
  $batch->add($request, $requestId);
}
$results = $batch->execute();
foreach($results as $responseId => $student) {
  $studentEmail = substr($responseId, strlen('response-') + 1);
  if ($student instanceof Google_Service_Exception) {
    $e = $student;
    printf("Error adding user '%s' to the course: %s\n", $studentEmail,
        $e->getMessage());
  } else {
    printf("User '%s' was added as a student to the course.\n",
        $student->profile->name->fullName, $courseId);
  }
}
$service->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post,  I have read through the quickstart docs and have succesfully used batch requests on other google services.  it just doesn't seem to be playing ball when enrolling students to a classroom